# Software where I can numerically evaluate multivariable integrals over a region?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods

I need, for example, to evaluate:

$$\iiint(x-1)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

over the region:

$$y=0,\, z=0,\, y+z=5,\, z=4-x^2$$
but I have no ways to verify if I did it right. I needed a form of numerical evaluation. Can I do it in wolfram alpha?

Comment: You probably need the full power of Mathematica (I'm not sure). If you write out your solution in your question someone here might check it for you.

Comment: [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=triple+integral+%28x-1%29dxdydz%2C+y%3D0%2C+z%3D0%2C+y%2Bz%3D5%2C+z%3D4-x^2) is the wolfram result. Whether or not that is correct, I haven't checked.

Comment: @Mattos this is not right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to compute the integral:$$\iiint_D(x-1)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z=\int_{-2}^2\int_0^{4-x^2}\int_0^{5-z} (x-1)\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}x$$
where $D$ is the region defined by the limits. I've included a plot of the region bounded by the surfaces below.

[image]

The integral can indeed be computed with software (I'm using Mathematica). There are several ways to do it via `Integrate`. Here's one using the standard `Integrate` form.

```
In[32]:= Integrate[x - 1, {x, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 4 - x^2}, {y, 0, 5 - z}]

Out[32]= -(544/15)
```

And here's another that integrates over the region.

```
In[36]:= Integrate[(x - 1) Boole[0 <= y <= 5 - z && 0 <= z <= 4 - x^2 && -2 <= x <= 2],
    {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]

Out[36]= -(544/15)
```

**Edit**: Mathematica code for graphics.

```
surfaces = ContourPlot3D[{y == 0, z == 0, y + z == 5, z == 4 - x^2},
    {x, -4, 4}, {y, -1, 6}, {z, -1, 5},
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.25], Mesh -> False];

region = RegionPlot3D[0 <= y <= 5 - z && 0 <= z <= 4 - x^2 && -2 <= x <= 2,
    {x, -4, 4}, {y, -1, 6}, {z, -1, 5}, MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> False];

Show[surfaces, region]
```

Comment: Pretty image! (although I guess the 3D plot function was built-in?)

Comment: @mathreadler Yes, I'm using `ContourPlot3D` for the solid and `RegionPlot3D` for the surfaces. I'll add the code for the graphics to my answer.